# Export PDF with jasper report

Tags: spring-boot, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to export PDF file with jasper report in a spring boot project, and this is my controller:

[image: exportcontroller]

so with this method the pdf file is exporting locally in my project, I want to change it so I can export it in a specified path on my pc.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directory and get the absolute path of this directory, then export the pdf to the created directory.

On Windows Machine like:-

```
File file = new File("C:/temp/output");
file.mkdirs();
  JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, file.getAbsolutePath 
+"report.pdf");
```

On Linux Machine:-

```
File file = new File("/opt/output");

file.mkdirs();
  JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, file.getAbsolutePath 
+"report.pdf");
```